# Heat map of binary data using R or Python

Tags: python, r

I have a binary data set of 0 and 1, where 0 is an absence and 1 is a presence of an event.

A sample of the data set looks like this:

```
events    germany    Italy 
Rain      0          1
hail      1          0
sunny     0          0
```

I'd like to get a red and white picture of this data in the form of heat map by reading the data from a file.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I use MeV software for this but somehow (i think because of the binary nature of data) the result is either completely red or completely white.

Comment: @Angelo I'm assuming by the tags that you would like to see both a `python` and a `R` solution. If so, next time please state that in the question.

Comment: Take a look at the tile geometry in ggplot2 for a good option.

Comment: I am guessing the reading the data from a file part is either known or a separate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reshape and ggplot2 in R

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(weather=c("Rain","Hail","Sunny"), Germany = c(0,1,0), Italy = c(1,0,0))

melt.data<-melt(dat, id.vars="weather", variable_name="country")

qplot(data=melt.data,
      x=country,
      y=weather,
      fill=factor(value),
      geom="tile")+scale_fill_manual(values=c("0"="white", "1"="red"))
```

[image]

Comment: How can I give input as a file, instead of dat <- data.frame(weather=c("Rain","Hail","Sunny"), Germany = c(0,1,0), Italy = c(1,0,0))
this line

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: In response to comments below, here is a sample data file (saved on disk as "data.txt"):

```
Rain  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
Hail  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
Sunny 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
```

In python, we can read the labels and plot this "heatmap" by:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
import pylab as plt

labels = loadtxt("data.txt", usecols=[0,],dtype=str)
A      = loadtxt("data.txt", usecols=range(1,10))

plt.imshow(A, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
plt.yticks(range(A.shape[0]), labels)

plt.show()
import pylab as plt
```

[image]

Comment: How can I read the binary matrix, instead of typing  A = [[0,1],[1,0],[0,0]] ?

Comment: @Angelo is the data in a file and does it look _exactly_ like what is posted in your question? If so, I'll edit my question to show how to read from a file - if not let me know what your data looks like. As it stands `A` _is_ a binary matrix (i.e. a two-dimensional array of zeros and ones).

Comment: It is a kind of a similar data matrix of 133 rows and 4 columns with column1 containing the events, while column 2,3,4 contain the binary data (0 or 1) indicating whether that even occurred in that country or not.

Comment: @Angelo I've edited the answer to reflect your data a bit more accurately. You can change "data.txt" to anything you want now, the label should be grabbed from the first column and the subsequent columns should be pulled correctly.

Comment: the image is good but very small. How can I increase the image size?

Comment: In pylab, the image is an interactive window. You can click on the save icon to save it to a png, or even better a pdf, where the resolution is perfect and can be blown up to arbitrary size. To programmatically save the image use the dpi setting in savefig http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10747/discussion-between-angelo-and-hooked)

Answer (score 4):

See `?image`. With your data

```
dat <- data.matrix(data.frame(Germany = c(0,1,0), Italy = c(1,0,0)))
rownames(dat) <- c("Rain","Hail","Sunny")
```

This gets us close:

```
image(z = dat, col = c("white","red"))
```

but better handling of axis labels would be nice... Try:

```
op <- par(mar = c(5,5,4,2) + 0.1)
image(z = dat, col = c("white","red"), axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 1, labels = rownames(dat), 
     at = seq(0, by = 0.5, length.out = nrow(dat)))
axis(side = 2, labels = colnames(dat), at = c(0,1), las = 1)
box()
par(op)
```

Which gives

[image: binary heatmap]

To have the heatmap the other way round, transpose `dat` (`image(z = t(dat), ....)`) and make in the `axis()` calls, change `side` to `2` in the first and `1` in the second call (and move the `las = 1` to the other call. I.e.:

```
op <- par(mar = c(5,5,4,2) + 0.1)
image(z = t(dat2), col = c("white","red"), axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 2, labels = rownames(dat2), 
     at = seq(0, by = 0.5, length.out = nrow(dat2)), las = 1)
axis(side = 1, labels = colnames(dat2), at = c(0,1))
box()
par(op)
```

Comment: How can I read a file, like the file in the question and still get the same result.

Comment: See ?read.table for most delimited types. There is the R Data Import/Export manual if your "file" is more complicated. Find the manual on CRAN.

Answer (score 2):

in R try:

```
library(bipartite)
mat<-matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,1),byrow=TRUE,nrow=3)
rownames(mat)<-c("Rain","hail","sunny")
colnames(mat)<-c("Germany","Italy")
visweb(mat,type="None")
```

for red squares and label size control:

```
visweb(mat,type="None",labsize=2,square="b",box.col="red")
```

Comment: How can i increase the font size? this is what i am doing 1. dat_matrix<-data.matrix(dat) 2. tiff("presenceGene.tiff") 3. visweb(dat_matrix,type="None") 4. dev.off().  i am getting an image which has a very small font size

Comment: `labsize=2` will make the text size 2.  try different sizes to get what you want i.e. `visweb(mat,type="None",labsize=2) `

Comment: plot size can be controlled with `plotsize=12` i think

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution in base R is:

```
rownames(dat) = dat$weather
heatmap(as.matrix(dat[,2:3]), scale='none')
```

... assuming that your data frame is called `dat`. The heatmap is not pretty but it's quick and easy. The first line is not necessary. It only serves to make the weather labels show in the heatmap.