# R preserving row order ggplot2 geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some categorical data and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10400762/163809) is very close to what I am trying to do, however in my case I have dates in the place of countries as seen in this example.  How can I create the plot with the original row order from the data.frame?  It appears that even though the factors are in the same order in `dat` and `melt.data` they are not ordered sequentially on the y axis in the plot.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(dates=c("01/01/2002", "09/15/2003", "05/31/2012"), Germany = c(0,1,0), Italy = c(1,0,0))
melt.data<-melt(dat, id.vars="dates", variable_name="country")

qplot(data=melt.data,
      x=country,
      y=dates,
      fill=factor(value),
      geom="tile")
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. In general `ggplot2` will plot in the order of the `levels` of the factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that date is stored as a character string. See `str(dat)` for a structure of the data.

By adding

```
dat$dates <- as.Date(dat$dates,"%m/%d/%Y")
```

after loading dat, you can get the dates in the original order.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `dat$dates` is a factor, and by default `R` has sorted the levels lexicographically. `R` does not know they are dates.

So

```
levels(dat$dates)
## [1] "01/01/2002" "05/31/2012" "09/15/2003"
```

and thererfore

```
order(dat$dates)
## [1] 1 3 2
```

If you want `R` to treat these as dates, then you can convert them to `Date` column

```
 dat$dates <- as.Date(as.character(dat$dates), format = '%m/%d/%Y')

  # now 
 order(dat$dates)
 ## 1 2 3
```

Which is what you want