# Heatmap type plot with binary vectors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data in the form of vectors like this:

```
[
[a, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[b, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[c, 1, 0, 1, 0],
...
]
```

I want to plot the data so that it looks kind of like this:
[image]

Where 0th element in each array is on the y axis and elements 1:4 of the array are plotted along the x axis. Specifically, each element 1:4 is plotted along a column and is yellow for `0` and purple for `1`.

What is such a plot called and how do I make one?

Comment: you might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398535/13285707), hope it helps

Comment: Another interesting resource to look at might be [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's called `imshow`/`matshow`:

```
# `lst` is your list
plt.imshow(np.array([a[1:] for a in lst]).T)       
plt.xticks(range(len(lst)),labels=[a[0] for a in lst])
```

Output:

[image]